# Properties Set procedure vs External functions

Tags: vb.net, properties

Let's say i have a property of type `List(Of String)`.

**First Option**

I can use the set procedure to execute the entire code and get the URL without an exetran funciton.

```
Private Property UrlList As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return pUrlList
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        'Do some long procedure.
         pUrlList = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Secont Option**

I can use an external funciton and call it it inside the Set procedure.

```
Private Property UrlList As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return pUrlList
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of String))
        value = GetURL(value)
        pUrlList = value
    End Set
End Property


Private Function GetURL(ByVal URLList As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    'Do the long procedure here.
    Return URLList
End Function
```

All in all, the two options, do the same thing and UrlList will get the same URL's in both ways.

**My Problem**

When I'm looking at various codes in SO and in many other places, properties are not used to execute the main code or the main functions, they are just used like fields, with some error handling inside them(If IsNothing() Then...type of things).

**My Question**

Why?
Why properties Set procedures are not used in the first option? Why should I use an external funciton when i can just do the code inside the Set procedure.

What would you recommnd me to do?Should I use functions all the time, diverse or use Set procedure?

Comment: RSS feed is an XML, right? Just download using WebClient.DownloadString and parse using XDocument. Should be way fewer lines of code that what you have now.

Comment: That is not the point of my question.

Comment: Then your point is not about RSS/Web, please remove everything relevant to RSS, and leave only the relevant parts.

Comment: think of properties as Adjectives like EyeColor, Height, Width, HairColor and think of Methods as Verbs ChangeHairColor, LoseWeight, MakeTallerByStandingOnToes.  DOING stuff when you change a property is not always desirable and more rarely expected by the consuming code.  Setting a SortOrder prop to Asc doesnt really mean I want to Sort you now, it means WHEN I sort this, I want it in ASC order.